# Como pegar os últimos n elementos de um Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Possuo um `service` que está recebendo um array `objeto` da API com a função abaixo:

```
getUltimosDados(n: number): Observable<Objeto[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Objeto[]>(this.enderecoDaApi + '/objetos/');
}
```

A função apresentada retorna todos os objetos de dentro do `Observable`. Porém quero trabalhar apenas com os últimos `n` objetos do vetor. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getUltimosDados(n: number): Observable<Objeto[]>{    
    return this.httpClient.get<Objeto[]>(this.enderecoDaApi + '/objetos/').pipe(
       map(arr=>arr.slice(-n))
    );    
}
```